# Need a key name for display sender name or number in twilio API for OTP

Tags: ios, twilio, twilio-api

Currently i need to display sender name or number in text message which was sent using twilio API for OTP..

I am not able to find "key" to send in parameters.. i searched in Twilio official Docs.

I am using Twilio API for OTP: https://api.authy.com/protected/json/phones/verification/

in header i am sending my API key

and parameters like this:

```
    `let parameters: [String: Any] = [
        "api_key": _twiloAPIKey,
        "via": "sms",
        "country_code": countryCode,
        "phone_number": phone,
        "code_length": 6,
    ]`
```

how to send Alphanumeric value in parameters?

i.e. I want to send "APPNAME" so that display app name on SMS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

You can't choose the sender name in the OTP API. We have worked to register an alphanumeric sender ID "AUTHMSG" that works in 79 countries and helps to improve deliverability rates and recognition.

Take a read of this blog post on the [AUTHMSG sender ID](https://www.twilio.com/blog/authmsg) to find out more.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I saw twilio docs for the same. It shows that we can personalise alphanumeric sender id, So this is for sending sms only?. And no way i can implement alphnum sender id in OTP?

Comment: When you are using the Authy APIs you don't have control over the sender name. If you were to implement this with the Twilio messaging API then you could change the sender ID.